# Ĉu "tago+n" aŭ "tag+e"?

Tags: word-usage

> 1- Ĵaŭde mi ĉiam manĝas en la sama restoracio.

Ĉu oni povas diri la frazon kun "Ĵaŭdon", anstataŭ "Ĵaŭde"?

> 2- Ili povas veni Ĵaŭdon.

Ĉu oni povas diri la frazon kun "Ĵaŭde", anstataŭ "Ĵaŭdon"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas tri alternativoj:

(a) ĵaŭdon : dum la sekva ĵaŭdo

(b) ĵaŭde : dum venontaj ĵaŭdoj

(c) je ĵaŭdo = ĵaŭdon

Notu, ke ne ĉiuj parolantoj faras la distingon inter (a) kaj (b). La alternativo (c) estas rara kaj bazas sur la ideo, ke oni povas anstataŭigi prepozicion per la akuzativo aŭ alidirekte.

1. …mi ĉiam manĝas en la sama restoracio.

Ĉar la frazo enhavas la vorton "ĉiam", temas pri ripeta ago, do "ĵaŭde".

2. Ili povas veni…

Verŝajne temas nur pri la sekva ĵaudo, do "ĵaŭdon".

Notu, ke oni kutime skribas la nomojn de tagoj kun malgrandaj literoj.

Comment: Mi pensas ke vi volis diri (c) je ĵaŭd**o**

Comment: Jes, vi pravas, mia mistajpo.

Comment: Dankegon Sinjoro Metsäkallas, pro via instrua respondo.

Answer (score 1):

`ĵaŭdo` estas singularo opone al `ĵaŭde` kiu povas validi por multnumbro.

`ĉiuĵaŭde` mi ankaŭ konas kiel formon, kaj plej klaras. Same `venontĵaŭde` / `tiuĵaŭde`.

`dum ĵaŭdoj` / `je ĵaŭdo` same faras distingon.

Answer (score 0):

Mi uzus "Ĵaŭde mi ĉiam manĝas en la sama restoracio"? Vi ankaŭ povas uzi "ĉiuĵaude" (every thursday). "Eĥoŝanĝo Ĉiuĵaŭde" estas frazo kiu kontenas ĉiu ĉapelita litero kiu baze signifas "echo change every thursday". Ĝi estas sensenza frazo sed ĝi servas sia celo.

"Ĵaude" signifas "on thursday". Ekzemple "la trajno alvenis ĉe la sesa kaj duono **vespere**" signifas "The train arrives at 6:30 **in the evening**".

Answer (score -3):

> Ĉu oni povas diri la frazon kun "Ĵaŭde", anstataŭ "Ĵaŭdon"?

jes, sed la signifo ne estus la sama.