Difference of sabaton and sabate
This sentence uses sabate instead of sabaton.

Multaj homoj ne laboras sabate kaj dimanĉe.

Does the sentence have a different meaning, if sabaton is instead used?

You might want to look at the answer https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5830/1872.

Multaj homoj ne laboras sabate kaj dimanĉe. = "Many people do not work on Saturday(s) and Sunday(s)."
This sentence is talking in a general way about those two days.
Multaj homoj ne laboras sabaton kaj dimanĉon = "Many people are not working on Saturday and Sunday."
In this sentence, the implication is that we are talking about a specific weekend. Given that dates are not specified, it probably means next weekend. Because of the use of the accusative "-n", Saturday and Sunday are definite points in time.
Having said that, you can also say, for instance, "Cxi-vespere mi ne laboros." But in this case, there is no chance of confusion, because "cxi-vespere" can only refer to one specific evening (tonight), not to evenings in general.
